# Upon using Scan.nextLine() the code is skipping the last entity

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I have a  scenario,where In need to search values in an Array..the array might consist of elements with space.

In the below code:-
I will enter the size of the array in the console, where as the code skipping the last entry,If have entered the array size as 5 it is considering only 4 rows

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n  = scan.nextInt();
    String [] nameArr = new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i <n;i++)
    {

     nameArr[i] = scan.nextLine();

    }

    System.out.println("Enter the name you want to search");
    String search = scan.nextLine();
```

When I change it as the below

```
for(int i=0;i <=n;i++)
```

I am getting the below Exception 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Array2list.main(Array2list.java:18)

Comment: Add `scan.nextLine()` after your `nextInt()` call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo?rq=1

Comment: just a side note, use i < nameArr.length(); instead of i < n.